# Not compatible code running loading dump file in VS 17

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to load a dump file created on a different computer running on a RelWithDebug .exe. I'm using the same source code that was used to generate the .exe and I have the .pdb file, also set the path to the .pdb file in visual studio but I keep getting the "Not Compatible Code Running" message when I try to use the dump file in visual studio.

what could be causing this issue?
are there any other requirement to get the dump file to work?

Comment: Have you configured Visual Studio to load symbols from the Microsoft symbol servers? (Menu -> Tools-> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols).

Comment: I have not tried it, does it just save the pdb file to make sure that I'm using the correct .pdb?

Comment: No, it downloads symbols for the Windows DLLs so that you get a better stack trace in the debugger.

Comment: PDB is generated by the compiler for the exact EXE it produces. It can’t be used for any other EXE, even compiled from the same source. Is that your case?